# Possible approaches of curve fitting of a damped cosine function [Regression]

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, curve-fitting

I've a set of data and I want to fit these data to a damped cosine function i.e. "A*.cos(K*x).*exp(-B*x)". To do this, I've used the following code, but the fitting is very bad. Can anyone suggest me to find the best fit? x & y data are the following:

```
x=[0, 1.3, 1.7, 1.72, 1.84, 1.98, 2.02, 2.16, 2.2, 2.2, 2.3, 2.38, 2.5, 2.55, 2.75, 2.8, 2.82, 2.84, 2.9, 2.92, 3.1, 3.13, 3.18, 3.19, 3.22, 3.3, 3.38, 3.44, 3.49, 3.62, 3.64, 3.72, 3.72, 3.75, 3.8, 3.82, 3.86, 3.92, 4.0, 4.07, 4.1, 4.1, 4.13, 4.14, 4.14, 4.17, 4.21, 4.24, 4.24, 4.24, 4.28, 4.3, 4.38, 4.49, 4.62, 4.62, 4.67, 4.72, 4.73, 4.74, 4.76, 4.76, 4.81, 4.81, 4.88, 4.89, 4.9, 4.9, 4.94, 4.96, 5.03, 5.05, 5.06, 5.1, 5.1, 5.15, 5.16, 5.16, 5.19, 5.22, 5.22, 5.3, 5.37, 5.41, 5.46, 5.56, 5.63, 5.65, 5.65, 5.73, 5.76, 5.81, 5.86, 5.91, 5.98, 6.03, 6.05, 6.05, 6.06, 6.11, 6.14, 6.22, 6.25, 6.27, 6.27, 6.3, 6.3, 6.31, 6.36, 6.42, 6.42, 6.47, 6.48, 6.5, 6.51, 6.58, 6.59, 6.62, 6.65, 6.66, 6.67, 6.69, 6.72, 6.77, 6.8, 6.84, 6.87, 6.91, 6.94, 6.94, 6.94, 7.05, 7.14, 7.17, 7.22, 7.23, 7.24, 7.32, 7.32, 7.35, 7.38, 7.4, 7.41, 7.42, 7.44, 7.45, 7.49, 7.5, 7.52, 7.54, 7.6, 7.72, 7.75, 7.81, 7.9, 7.92, 7.95, 7.97, 7.98, 7.99, 8.02, 8.03, 8.03, 8.05, 8.06, 8.07, 8.1, 8.12, 8.14, 8.19, 8.2, 8.21, 8.24, 8.25, 8.28, 8.28, 8.29, 8.32, 8.38, 8.38, 8.43, 8.49, 8.52, 8.54, 8.54, 8.57, 8.7, 8.75, 8.75, 8.78, 8.79, 8.88, 8.88, 8.93, 8.95, 9.0, 9.01, 9.02, 9.03, 9.06, 9.07, 9.11, 9.14, 9.16, 9.17, 9.18, 9.19, 9.2, 9.3, 9.33, 9.44, 9.46, 9.59, 9.62, 9.62, 9.64, 9.66, 9.71, 9.73, 9.73, 9.75, 9.76, 9.76, 9.79, 9.88, 9.9, 9.93, 9.93, 9.95, 9.99, 10.01, 10.03, 10.04, 10.05, 10.07, 10.11, 10.13, 10.18, 10.22, 10.22, 10.31, 10.37, 10.38, 10.41, 10.42, 10.44, 10.5, 10.52, 10.55, 10.56, 10.56, 10.58, 10.6, 10.66, 10.68, 10.68, 10.69, 10.7, 10.73, 10.75, 10.81, 10.93, 10.96, 10.98, 10.98, 11.02, 11.04, 11.1, 11.14, 11.15, 11.15, 11.17, 11.19, 11.21, 11.23, 11.24, 11.28, 11.3, 11.31, 11.32, 11.33, 11.4, 11.42, 11.48, 11.5, 11.51, 11.6, 11.62, 11.62, 11.63, 11.65, 11.72, 11.74, 11.74, 11.94, 11.95, 11.98, 12.02, 12.02, 12.03, 12.04, 12.09, 12.11, 12.17, 12.2, 12.23, 12.26, 12.3, 12.31, 12.33, 12.33, 12.37, 12.38, 12.61, 12.63, 12.69, 12.7, 12.74, 12.79, 12.8, 12.84, 12.87, 12.9, 12.91, 12.92, 12.94, 13.0, 13.19, 13.2, 13.26, 13.29, 13.3, 13.31, 13.31, 13.34, 13.35, 13.36, 13.44, 13.48, 13.52, 13.59, 13.78, 13.83, 13.88, 13.98, 14.02, 14.05, 14.07, 14.1, 14.14, 14.19, 14.25, 14.33, 14.36, 14.38, 14.41, 14.46, 14.47, 14.53, 14.54, 14.57, 14.69, 14.72, 14.77, 14.78, 14.78, 14.8, 14.82, 14.82, 14.91, 14.92, 14.96, 14.96, 15.05, 15.09, 15.17, 15.2, 15.21, 15.25, 15.26, 15.31, 15.32, 15.36, 15.36, 15.4, 15.4, 15.4, 15.41, 15.47, 15.52, 15.6, 15.61, 15.61, 15.63, 15.65, 15.71, 15.77, 15.8, 15.84, 15.86, 15.88, 15.94, 15.94, 15.97, 15.98, 16.02, 16.03, 16.27, 16.43, 16.56, 16.64, 16.64, 16.64, 16.68, 16.88, 16.91, 16.92, 16.93, 16.97, 16.99, 17.0, 17.01, 17.02, 17.05, 17.13, 17.21, 17.32, 17.45, 17.59, 17.79, 17.8, 17.81, 17.87, 17.9, 17.92, 17.93, 17.93, 17.97, 17.98, 18.02, 18.05, 18.08, 18.11, 18.2, 18.24, 18.4, 18.48, 18.5, 18.51, 18.59, 18.65, 18.76, 18.76, 18.86, 18.86, 18.86, 18.87, 18.9, 18.92, 18.93, 19.05, 19.06, 19.17, 19.26, 19.27, 19.41, 19.47, 19.48, 19.54, 19.6, 19.66, 19.67, 19.68, 19.8, 19.9, 20.01, 20.04, 20.1, 20.49, 20.49, 20.5, 20.56, 20.65, 20.65, 20.7, 20.71, 20.78, 20.91, 21.11, 21.19, 21.2, 21.28, 21.29, 21.58, 21.62, 21.7, 21.7, 21.76, 21.76, 21.84, 21.85, 21.87, 21.9, 21.94, 22.0, 22.02, 22.09, 22.16, 22.3, 22.3, 22.41, 22.51, 22.53, 22.71, 22.77, 22.94, 23.17, 23.25, 23.33, 23.72, 23.87, 24.12, 24.14, 24.19, 24.34, 24.4, 24.6, 24.62, 24.62, 24.8, 25.01, 25.13, 25.4, 25.42, 25.81, 25.85, 25.89, 26.03, 26.17, 26.22, 26.41, 26.98, 27.01, 27.02, 27.06, 27.17, 27.49, 27.73, 28.14, 28.23, 28.37, 28.56, 28.83, 28.84, 30.32, 30.57, 31.95, 33.23, 33.46, 33.81, 33.85, 34.44]
y=[1, 0.97119140625, 0.7978515625, 0.88525390625, 0.87255859375, 0.9228515625, 0.9677734375, 0.931640625, 0.953125, 0.96484375, 0.67041015625, 0.685546875, 0.8740234375, 0.82958984375, 0.79736328125, 0.8046875, 0.87841796875, 0.62109375, 0.5986328125, 0.826171875, 0.57470703125, 0.921875, 0.51025390625, 0.87939453125, 0.79638671875, 0.76513671875, 0.6318359375, 0.80126953125, 0.58447265625, 0.7392578125, 0.7802734375, 0.5703125, 0.77587890625, 0.6748046875, 0.826171875, 0.88671875, 0.85986328125, 0.80078125, 0.7099609375, 0.6474609375, 0.5439453125, 0.7001953125, 0.8896484375, 0.87744140625, 0.9306640625, 0.7021484375, 0.8603515625, 0.302490234375, 0.66552734375, 0.75390625, 0.71240234375, 0.52392578125, 0.8662109375, 0.66650390625, 0.35986328125, 0.46044921875, 0.58984375, 0.7548828125, 0.80322265625, 0.8193359375, 0.27880859375, 0.638671875, 0.53466796875, 0.65625, 0.302734375, 0.429443359375, 0.251708984375, 0.6982421875, 0.7626953125, 0.65966796875, 0.62451171875, 0.47998046875, 0.65087890625, -0.0224456787109375, 0.748046875, 0.70458984375, 0.43603515625, 0.53369140625, 0.391845703125, 0.4921875, 0.75830078125, 0.828125, 0.4521484375, 0.701171875, 0.83251953125, 0.55908203125, 0.80078125, 0.297119140625, 0.54150390625, 0.374755859375, 0.60205078125, 0.66064453125, 0.412353515625, 0.30615234375, 0.2486572265625, 0.432861328125, 0.1175537109375, 0.70849609375, -0.20458984375, 0.5771484375, 0.254638671875, 0.68359375, -0.05792236328125, 0.34033203125, 0.37060546875, 0.56982421875, 0.8056640625, 0.09881591796875, 0.65625, 0.23388671875, 0.491455078125, 0.331787109375, 0.1302490234375, 0.791015625, 0.5986328125, 0.399658203125, 0.61376953125, 0.53076171875, 0.210693359375, 0.4423828125, 0.5751953125, 0.495361328125, 0.2384033203125, 0.7333984375, 0.39111328125, 0.1533203125, 0.4951171875, 0.28515625, 0.048065185546875, 0.345947265625, 0.3798828125, -0.0243988037109375, 0.576171875, 0.2127685546875, 0.417724609375, 0.408447265625, 0.5673828125, 0.1680908203125, 0.58203125, 0.6337890625, 0.1171875, 0.59814453125, 0.321044921875, 0.133056640625, 0.2437744140625, 0.005306243896484375, 0.1336669921875, -0.5703125, 0.5693359375, 0.418701171875, 0.1077880859375, -0.1431884765625, 0.51220703125, 0.0021724700927734375, 0.1805419921875, 0.5546875, 0.35107421875, 0.17919921875, 0.2413330078125, 0.1287841796875, 0.032440185546875, 0.435546875, 0.5166015625, 0.227783203125, 0.478271484375, 0.11627197265625, 0.384033203125, 0.54541015625, 0.008514404296875, 0.1456298828125, 0.2265625, 0.6953125, 0.5576171875, 0.471435546875, 0.146240234375, 0.673828125, 0.1785888671875, 0.278564453125, 0.03521728515625, 0.197021484375, 0.4091796875, 0.2105712890625, 0.6767578125, 0.292236328125, 0.61669921875, 0.5078125, 0.48486328125, -0.05682373046875, 0.3623046875, 0.441162109375, 0.0307769775390625, 0.10516357421875, 0.4541015625, 0.53076171875, -0.0219879150390625, 0.59423828125, 0.07867431640625, 0.383544921875, 0.64111328125, -0.038848876953125, -0.1036376953125, 0.0213470458984375, -0.0007333755493164062, 0.556640625, 0.462158203125, 0.470458984375, 0.305908203125, 0.436767578125, 0.1883544921875, 0.07977294921875, 0.54150390625, -0.11492919921875, 0.043975830078125, 0.07244873046875, 0.1573486328125, 0.141357421875, 0.52294921875, 0.10198974609375, -0.13916015625, 0.2314453125, 0.1143798828125, 0.1435546875, 0.361083984375, 0.2822265625, 0.6767578125, 0.272216796875, 0.035369873046875, 0.54638671875, 0.35986328125, 0.1324462890625, 0.283935546875, -0.359375, 0.113525390625, 0.444580078125, 0.08453369140625, -0.0662841796875, 0.60302734375, -0.058258056640625, 0.2232666015625, 0.572265625, 0.1064453125, 0.234130859375, 0.316650390625, 0.5888671875, 0.034881591796875, 0.038330078125, 0.09259033203125, 0.387939453125, 0.31640625, 0.09906005859375, 0.295654296875, 0.06787109375, 0.2222900390625, 0.51318359375, -0.2303466796875, 0.08935546875, 0.01538848876953125, 0.301513671875, -0.0555419921875, 0.167236328125, 0.348388671875, 0.259033203125, -0.12115478515625, 0.21875, 0.2255859375, -0.007389068603515625, 0.352783203125, 0.280517578125, 0.477294921875, 0.0997314453125, 0.241455078125, 0.207763671875, 0.485107421875, -0.04827880859375, -0.1048583984375, 0.301025390625, 0.333984375, 0.17041015625, 0.16552734375, 0.533203125, 0.25439453125, 0.1949462890625, -0.0609130859375, 0.1912841796875, 0.149658203125, -0.01195526123046875, 0.100830078125, -0.150390625, 0.134765625, 0.2003173828125, 0.323974609375, 0.2391357421875, 0.0166473388671875, 0.54443359375, 0.2197265625, 0.270751953125, 0.07989501953125, 0.01105499267578125, 0.1248779296875, 0.1544189453125, 0.462646484375, -0.322021484375, 0.18017578125, 0.474609375, 0.485595703125, 0.0941162109375, -0.08319091796875, 0.08697509765625, 0.10546875, 0.1292724609375, 0.50830078125, 0.395751953125, 0.0179290771484375, 0.0831298828125, 0.406982421875, 0.2496337890625, 0.2181396484375, -0.3525390625, -0.225341796875, 0.072265625, 0.420654296875, 0.24072265625, 0.020782470703125, 0.02197265625, -0.09930419921875, 0.080810546875, -0.0816650390625, 0.444580078125, -0.052215576171875, 0.107666015625, 0.466552734375, 0.33935546875, 0.23974609375, 0.384033203125, 0.301025390625, 0.1275634765625, -0.253173828125, -0.2286376953125, -0.0204925537109375, 0.1527099609375, 0.256103515625, 0.09405517578125, 0.2166748046875, 0.0221710205078125, 0.1700439453125, 0.1451416015625, -0.09765625, 0.1456298828125, 0.26708984375, 0.045654296875, -0.007354736328125, -0.037353515625, 0.1895751953125, 0.55615234375, 0.039764404296875, 0.12432861328125, 0.335205078125, 0.66943359375, 0.373779296875, 0.37646484375, -0.2939453125, 0.261474609375, 0.24365234375, -0.19384765625, -0.072265625, 0.2213134765625, 0.09710693359375, 0.302734375, 0.383544921875, 0.48193359375, 0.308837890625, 0.058074951171875, 0.42431640625, 0.21142578125, 0.033294677734375, 0.22265625, 0.26953125, -0.027435302734375, 0.42529296875, 0.1778564453125, 0.1683349609375, 0.52734375, 0.0005445480346679688, 0.11578369140625, -0.1346435546875, 0.19384765625, 0.331298828125, 0.349609375, 0.376953125, 0.333984375, 0.28466796875, 0.0650634765625, 0.1923828125, -0.2154541015625, 0.361572265625, 0.44580078125, 0.44287109375, 0.04351806640625, -0.2607421875, 0.5419921875, 0.271240234375, 0.114501953125, 0.375, 0.306884765625, -0.2227783203125, 0.3466796875, 0.137939453125, 0.193115234375, 0.311767578125, -0.0274810791015625, 0.0167694091796875, 0.35595703125, 0.54736328125, -0.058563232421875, 0.0077056884765625, -0.2330322265625, 0.326171875, 0.0859375, -0.235595703125, 0.197021484375, 0.5576171875, 0.51611328125, 0.40087890625, 0.35986328125, 0.01483154296875, -0.077392578125, 0.277587890625, 0.12103271484375, 0.384521484375, 0.59765625, 0.353515625, 0.44091796875, 0.0006513595581054688, -0.01324462890625, 0.30029296875, 0.310302734375, 0.382080078125, 0.27099609375, 0.291015625, -0.158447265625, 0.11834716796875, 0.1761474609375, 0.2432861328125, 0.00070953369140625, 0.406494140625, 0.294921875, 0.03253173828125, 0.46337890625, 0.27294921875, 0.342041015625, 0.08038330078125, -0.11114501953125, 0.312744140625, 0.3662109375, 0.42626953125, 0.452392578125, 0.5439453125, 0.4130859375, -0.21728515625, 0.352783203125, -0.037506103515625, 0.341064453125, 0.4248046875, 0.306640625, -0.012786865234375, 0.042449951171875, 0.272216796875, 0.3134765625, 0.16455078125, 0.54052734375, 0.447021484375, 0.0677490234375, 0.401123046875, 0.290771484375, 0.12176513671875, -0.059112548828125, -0.151123046875, 0.1878662109375, -0.07684326171875, 0.01140594482421875, 0.481201171875, 0.2120361328125, 0.1907958984375, 0.29248046875, 0.050689697265625, 0.308837890625, 0.371337890625, 0.1312255859375, 0.34765625, 0.298583984375, 0.446044921875, -0.2298583984375, 0.171875, -0.184814453125, 0.5068359375, 0.310546875, 0.324462890625, 0.25, 0.53076171875, 0.5400390625, 0.231689453125, 0.671875, -0.1876220703125, 0.412109375, 0.5546875, 0.049224853515625, 0.2388916015625, 0.5869140625, 0.11663818359375, 0.61767578125, 0.31591796875, 0.297119140625, 0.107666015625, 0.56005859375, 0.129638671875, -0.278564453125, 0.279052734375, 0.0285491943359375, 0.5712890625, -0.212646484375, -0.2064208984375, -0.11956787109375, -0.2783203125, -0.421630859375, -0.194580078125, 0.4541015625, 0.51171875, 0.208740234375, 0.395263671875, -0.252197265625, -0.17578125, -0.322509765625, 0.5654296875, 0.4208984375, -0.412353515625, 0.1898193359375, 0.193603515625, 0.541015625, 0.065185546875, 0.6015625, 0.21923828125, -0.06341552734375, 0.390380859375, -0.31201171875, 0.58251953125, 0.307373046875, 0.056610107421875, -0.140869140625, -0.0220184326171875, -0.07080078125, -0.26220703125, -0.313232421875, 0.439208984375, 0.38427734375, -0.18603515625, -0.095458984375, 0.164306640625, -0.12548828125, -0.1468505859375, 0.1876220703125, 0.2489013671875, -0.14013671875]


from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import least_squares
x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)
def fit_cosine(x, y):
    guess_amp = 1 # A
    guess_wave_no = .05# K
    guess_dampcoeff = 0 # B
    guess = np.array([guess_amp, guess_wave_no, guess_dampcoeff])

    def cos_func(x, A, K, B): return A * np.cos(K*x)*np.exp(-1*B*x)
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(cos_func, x, y, p0=guess, maxfev=5000)
    A, K, B = popt
    fitfunc = lambda x: A * np.cos(K*x)* np.exp(-1*B*x)
    return {"amp": A, "omega": K, "decay": B, "fitfunc": fitfunc, "maxcov": np.max(pcov), "rawres": (guess, popt, pcov)}

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
res = fit_cosine(x, y)
print("Amplitude=%(amp)s, WaveNumber =%(omega)s, DampingCoefficient = %(decay)s, Max. Cov.=%(maxcov)s" % res)
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x, y, label="Coherence")
#plt.plot(x, res["fitfunc"](x), "r-", label="y fit curve", linewidth=2)
plt.legend(loc="best")
plt.show()
```

Based on the model, as proposed by @JJcquilin 'y=(1-A+A*cos(K * x))*exp(-1 * B * x)', I tried to plot in the following 02 ways.
#* Method 01 : curve_fitting*#

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit, least_squares
import numpy as np
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)
A=1
K = .2
B = .03# B
guess = np.array([A, K, B])
def cos_func(x, A, K, B): 
    y = (1-A+A*np.cos(K * x))*np.exp(-1 * B * x)
    return y
# Method 02: Non-linear least-squares with bounds on the variables
def model(x,A,K,B):
    return (1-A+A*np.cos(K * x))*np.exp(-1 * B * x)

def error(params):
    A, K, B = params
    model_func = model(x, A, K, B)
    z = y - model_func
    return z
f_scale = 0.1
ls_bound = least_squares(error, x0, loss='soft_l1', f_scale=f_scale)
y_fitting = model(x, *ls_bound.x)
#########################
# non-linear least squares to fit the damped cosine function
fit_val, fit_cov = curve_fit(cos_func, x, y, p0=guess, method='trf')
fit_cosine = cos_func(x, *fit_val)
plt.figure()
colors = itertools.cycle(["r", "b", "c", "m", "c", "r"])
plt.scatter(x, y, color=next(colors), s=6, label='Data')
plt.plot(x, fit_cosine, "k--", linewidth=1, label=(f'Non-linear_LSM'))
plt.plot(x, y_fitting, "b--", linewidth=1, label=(f'Non-linear_LSM_bounds,f_scale = {f_scale}'))
plt.ylim(-1, 1.1)
plt.xlim(0, 35)
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 17})
plt.xlabel("Distance [Meter]")
plt.ylabel("Real part of coherence")
plt.title('Curve fitting of a damped cosine function')
plt.grid(True) 
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

Comments on the plot:

1. From the plot, it is seen that non-linear LSM with bounds fits better in the region ('x=3' to 'x=14') while the other method outperforms in the rest of the plot.
2. Both the curve generated from same initial condition
3. If I decrese the 'f_scale' the plot will show pulsating nature (tends to unstable!).
4. I do believe there are a lot of techniques to fit the data well that I don't know all those. Anyone may come forward and show/suggest me to better fitting of the data.

Any suggestions in these context will be appreciated.

Comment: Your fit is probably fine. But you fit to `cos_func`, yet you define a separate (lambda) function `fitfunc` to plot the evaluation. There is no need for that: just re-use `cos_func` with the fitted parameters. In fact, `cos_func` has a `-1` in the exponent, where as `fitfunc` has not. That is probably your problem.

Comment: @9769953, thank you for pointing out the error. Now the fitting is better. But do you have any suggestion to improve the fitting? Suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: The fitting will only be improved by changing your model (as is done in, for example, the current answer), or possibly (but not always) providing better starting parameters (closer to what you expect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fitting is difficult due to the high level of scatter.

A significantly better fitting is obtained in adding the parameter C in the equation.

[image]

IN ADDITION in order to answer to some comments :

The method leading to the above result consists in two steps.

First step : a non-conventional method which is not iterative an doesn't requires initial "guessed" values of the parameters. The general principle is explained in this paper : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales

Since the case of the function y(x)=(A * cos(K * x) + C) * exp(-B * x) is not explicitly treated in the paper the application to this function is given below :

[image]

It is not rare that people not familiar with this method make mistake in coding and say that the calculus fails. A lot of time is lost in discussions before the mistake be found and corrected. In order to avoid wasting time a "test" sheet is provided below. With the very small data it is easy for the user to check his code in comparing each intermediate numerical value to the correct values.

[image]

Then the method can be used with the big data given by the OP. The result is :

[image]

Don't be surprised that the values of the parameters are not exactly the same as the values given on the first figure at begining of my answer. This is because the criteria of fitting is not the same.

In his question the OP doesn't specify a criteria of fitting (LMSE, or LMAE, or LMSRE, or etc.). To each criteria of fitting correspond a different result. When the scatter is large the results can be very different one to the others. Since the scatter is very large in the present case, one cannot avoid to chose a particular criteria of fitting. If not the result is not unique. That is why a second step is necessary in the present case. But this not a general necessity.

Second step (Eventually):

We have to chose a criteria of fitting. For example Least Mean Square Errors.

A non-linear method of regression (in which the chosen criteria is implemented) must be used. They is a lot of software. The calculus is iterative and one have to give some "guessed" initial values to start the iteration.

In case of large scatter the convergence is not always good. The result might be far to be good with eventually failure if the initial values are not close to the correct values which are unknown. This is (partially) avoid thanks to the above first step. One can use the above values of K,B,A,C as rather good initial values. That is what was done to compute the values written on the first figure in my answer. This explains why the first figure is different from the last one.

NOTE :

To be honest one must acknowledge that the above method isn't infallible, especially in case of large scatter. I am surprized that a not too bad result be obtained. With three numerical integrations I was expecting much more difficulty. Certainly the large number of points is favourable. May be we are lucky with this data. We could have worse results with other set of data.

Comment: Your plot looks pretty good. I've  tried with & without 'p0' but most of the cases, I got a negative value of 'A'. Can you please share the code you have executed? @jjacquelin

Comment: I've plotted the similar dataset and got the value of 'A' something like '[-2.52,  -3.14,   0.49,   0.2,   0.25,   0.32,   0.38,   0.39, 0.43,   0.48,   0.54,   0.68,   0.74,   0.77,   0.77, 198.24,
 0.94]'. Do you think these values are consistent (especially A= 198.24)? How can I get consistent values of A? Any suggestion is highly appreciated. Thank you for your support. @JJacquelin

Comment: A is a single value; how do you even obtain an array of values?

Comment: ahh, I've various set of data (i.e., Xi & Yi; i=1,2,3......,N). For every set of value, I got various fitted value of 'A'. @9769953

Comment: @CEB. See the addition to my first answer expecially about your question concerning code and software.

Comment: Thanks@JJacquelin for your nice effort and analysis. As I want to do model a physical system which gives the magnitude '1' at the initial condition (i.e. x=0, in this case). So, I prefer to choose, y=f(x)=Acos(Kx)*exp(-1*B*x), also I hope your proposed equation also fit. But to fit one step better, I want to level up the fitting blue line (for x=0 to x=10). Do you suggest any additional mathematical function/parameter(s) to better match of these scattered values? Thanks

Comment: The condition y(0)=1 is also satisfied with the function y(x)=(A * cos(Kx)+C) * exp(-B * x) in adding the condition $C=1-A$. On the above numerical result one observes that A+C=1.004 which is very close to 1 compare to the level of scatter of the data. If you had specified in your question the condition $y(0)=1$ I would have treated the case of the function y(x)=(A * cos(Kx)+1-A) * exp(-Bx). Sorry, now I don't want spend more time on this question.

Comment: @JJacquelin, I want to fix A=1.0 as at x=0. To set the value of A=1 in the 'cos_func',  after fitting, I got the value of A is higher than unity (as the latest figure of Jean). Can you suggest how the blue line should start the journey from y=1 (at x=0)? Still, I'm struggling with the fitting. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Wow, just had a look (made the first integral by hand) and have to say, quite a beast to get it work via a differential equation or as here integro-equation. Hence the necessity of `SSSk` and "...now I don't want spend more time on this..." Nevertheless, would be nice to get the steps on how to formulate the according equation. Nice work, once again, though. Cheers

Comment: @mikuszefski, could you please suggest me how to move forward with the integral equations [First Step that Jean proposed] via python. I try to implement this in python, so any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @CEB [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69527266/803359) is an example where I used Python to solve the case for a Gaussian. As you can see from my comments above, it is by far more complicated to get to the final coefficients here, but the implementation should be very similar. It might help to notice, that the 6x6 symmetric matrix actually is `( s, ss, sss, x², x, 1) ( s, ss, sss, x², x, 1 ).T `, i.e.the dyadic.

Comment: @JJacquelin; I've a question in mind...how do you justify the constant (C) in a physical system? I mean, what is the physical significance of the constant C in a damped cosine equation? Does it mean at `t=0` (before damping starts), there is some noise presents/added with the amplitude of cosine wave?

Comment: The constant C is not justified on physical vewpoint. This is only the result of mathematical inspection. One could also try a model of this kind : y= (A * cos(K * x) + C * sin(K * x) ) * exp(-B * x) or other functions in expecting even better fitting.

Comment: @JJacquelin, I'm really impressed to read your comments. I'm curious how do you say about these kinds of functions (probably the function will give a better fit, I didn't try though). As a mathematician, probably you have some intuition or background calculation, really fall in love to your arbitrary functions.......Very good luck for you.