# gaussian fitting inaccurate for lower peak width using Python

Tags: python, optimization, curve-fitting, gaussian

I am trying to fit Gaussian to a noisy absorption spectrum. However, it doesn't seem to work well for all situations. When I try to decrease peak width to e.g. peak_width=10, the below code doenst produce a good fit, just a line. Again, if I moved the location of the peak further right x_peak_loc=160, it also doesn't work. How can I produce a better fit for these situations? Thanks! Below is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate as integrate
def func(x, a, x0, sigma):
    #return a*(1/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi*sigma**2 ))) *np.exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sigma**2))
    return a*np.exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*sigma**2))
amplitude=-10
peak_width=30
x_peak_loc=70

# Generating clean data
x = np.linspace(0, 200, 1000)
y = func(x, amplitude,x_peak_loc, peak_width)
# Adding noise to the data
mn = 0
N=0.2
std=np.sqrt(N)
noise2=np.random.normal(mn,std,size=len(x))
yn = y + noise2
fig = mpl.figure(1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y, c='k', label='analytic function')
ax.scatter(x, yn, s=5, label='fake noisy data')
fig.savefig('model_and_noise.png')
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, yn)
print (popt)

ym = func(x, popt[0], popt[1], popt[2])
ax.plot(x, ym, c='r', label='Best fit')
ax.legend()
fig.savefig('model_fit.png')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.xlabel("v")
plt.ylabel("f(v)")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you say spectrum so I guess there is more than one peak. In such a case the [`scipy.signal.find_peaks()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html) can be very useful.In case of peaks that can be isolated there is definitively no need for machine-learning overkill as it can be done by simple linear fits as described by [Jean Jacquelin](https://de.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales)

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.integrate import cumtrapz

def func( x, a, x0, sigma ):
    return a * np.exp( -( x - x0 )**2 / ( 2 * sigma**2 ) )
    
amplitude = -10
peak_width = 30
x_peak_loc = 160

# Generating clean data
xl = np.linspace( 0, 200, 1000 )
y0 = func( xl, amplitude, x_peak_loc, peak_width )

mn = 0
N = 0.2
std = np.sqrt( N )
noise2 = np.random.normal( mn, std, size=len( xl ) )
yl = y0 + noise2

"""
Most simple implementation of the linear fit of mu and sigma
"""
nul = yl - yl[0]

Sk = cumtrapz( yl, x=xl, initial=0 )
Tk = cumtrapz( xl * yl, x=xl, initial=0 )

MX = [
        [ np.dot( Sk, Sk ), np.dot( Sk, Tk ) ],
        [ np.dot( Sk, Tk ), np.dot( Tk, Tk ) ]
    ]
Vek = [ np.dot( nul, Sk ), np.dot( nul, Tk ) ]

res = np.dot( np.linalg.inv( MX ), Vek )
sig = np.sqrt( -1 / res[1] )
mu = res[0] * sig**2 
print( sig )
print( mu )
"""
Most simple linear fit of amplitude, probably not required but...hey.
"""
fk = func( xl, 1, mu, sig )
amp = np.dot( yl, fk ) / np.dot( fk, fk )
print( amp )
print( "probably quite close, already")

popt, pcov = curve_fit( func, xl, yl, p0=( sig, mu, amp ) ) 
print( popt )

fig = plt.figure( 1 )
ax = fig.add_subplot( 1, 1, 1 )
ax.plot( xl, y0, c='k', label="analytic function" )
ax.scatter( xl, yl, s=5, label="fake noisy data" )
ym = func( xl, *popt )
ax.plot( xl, ym, c='r', label="Best fit" )
ax.legend()
fig.savefig( "model_fit.png" )
plt.legend( loc="lower left" )
plt.xlabel( "v" )
plt.ylabel( "f(v)" )
plt.show()
```

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for sharing the method of Jacquelin. His method is also 10-20x faster on my system: `%timeit jacquelin_method(xl, yl)`
`245 µs ± 8.15 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)` versus `%timeit curvefit_method(xl, yl)` `5 ms ± 82.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`. Btw `cumtrapz` is not there anymore in the lastest versions of SciPy. You can probably use `scipy.integrate.quad` in the latest version instead.

Comment: @Roald I have 1.5.4 on Python3 with `cumtrapz()` present. In any case `quad()` needs a callable  and not a list of data, so that wouldn't work. If you really do not have it, a cumulative list integration should  not be to hard to write. you could make a spline fit, or some other piecewise thing to get a callable and feed that to quad. Not my favorite, though.

Comment: For 1.6.1, which I have, `cumtrapz()` is present as well.  I was just looking for the documentation and could only find a page for [scipy v=0.18.1](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.cumtrapz.html). There was no documentation for the latest one (1.7.1), so I assumed it was removed. But maybe it is still there.

Comment: @Roald I've seen that, tried to pip update, which changed me from 1.5.3 to 1.5.4,  I think.  `cumtrapz` present. No idea about the announced 1.7.1 though.

Comment: @Roald I guess it is still there. In the 1.7.1 docs in the section "Integrating using Samples" the "...trapezoid and simpson..." are linked.The first one then shows as next page  [scipy.integrate.cumulative_trapezoid](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.cumulative_trapezoid.html). It is still there; in the section of ODE's...dunno why and the search function is not working.

Comment: @mikuszefski works beautifully, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in using `curve_fit` or any gradient based algorithms. They tend to get stuck on local minima when working with noisy data. Sometimes you are lucky, sometimes you are not. If you increase noise magnitude, you will get the same (unfortunate) effect as with changing peak width.

You should either provide some good initial guess or change fit method to something completly different. You need to search space of function parameters  using some [hyperparameter optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperparameter_optimization) method.

Maybe some simple cascaded (with increasing precision) grid search will be enough for you?