# how to optimise fitting of gauss-hermite function in python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting, gaussian

What I have done so far:

I am trying to fit noisy data (which I generated myself by adding random noise to my function) to Gauss-Hermite function that I have defined. It works well in some cases for lower values of h3 and h4 but every once in a while it will produce a really bad fit even for lower h3, h4 values, and for higher h3, h4 values, it always gives a bad fit.

My code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Let's define the Gauss-Hermite function
#a=amplitude, x0=location of peak, sig=std dev, h3, h4
def gh_func(x, a, x0, sig, h3, h4):
   
    return a*np.exp(-.5*((x-x0)/sig)**2)*(1+h3*((-np.sqrt(3))*((x-x0)/sig)+(2/np.sqrt(3))*((x-x0)/sig)**3)+ h4*((np.sqrt(6)/4)+(-np.sqrt(6))*((x-x0)/sig)**2+(np.sqrt(6)/3)*(((x-x0)/sig)**4)))

#generate clean data
x = np.linspace(-10, 20, 100)
y = gh_func(x, 10, 5, np.sqrt(3), -0.10,-0.03) #it gives okay fit for h3=-0.10, h4=-0.03 but bad fits for higher values like h3=-0.4 and h4=-0.3.

#add noise to data

noise=np.random.normal(0,np.sqrt(0.5),size=len(x))
yn = y + noise

fig = mpl.figure(1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y, c='k', label='analytic function')
ax.scatter(x, yn, s=5, label='fake noisy data')
fig.savefig('model_and_noise_h3h4.png')
# Executing curve_fit on noisy data
popt, pcov = curve_fit(gh_func, x, yn)

#popt returns the best fit values for parameters of the given model (func)


print('Fitted Parameters (Gaus_Hermite):\na = %.10f , x0 = %.10f , sig = %.10f\nh3 = %.10f , h4 = %.10f' \
%(popt[0],popt[1],popt[2],popt[3],popt[4]))

ym = gh_func(x, popt[0], popt[1], popt[2], popt[3], popt[4])
ax.plot(x, ym, c='r', label='Best fit')
ax.legend()
fig.savefig('model_fit_h3h4.png')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.xlabel("v")
plt.ylabel("f(v)")
```

What I want to do:

I want to find a better fitting method than just curve_fit from scipy.optimize but I am not sure what I can use. Even if we end up using curve_fit, I need a way to produce better fits by providing initial guesses for the parameters which are generated automatically, e.g. one approach for only single peak gaussian is described in the accepted answer of this post (Jean Jacquelin's method):[gaussian fitting inaccurate for lower peak width using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69516007/gaussian-fitting-inaccurate-for-lower-peak-width-using-python). But this is just for mu,sigma and amplitude not h3,h4.

Besides curve_fit from scipy.optimize, I think there's one called lmfit: https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/  but I am not sure how I will implement it in my code. I do not want to use manual initial guesses for the parameters. I want to be able to find the fitting automatically.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: (1) To me, the fit (red line) to the noise-free data (black line) is quite good. The added noise is larger than the diff between red and black lines. Reducing the stddev of noise would likely result in better fits. (2) Two different parameter sets (with 33-50% different `h4`) can produce similar curves. This is an inherent model identifiability problem with the GH function you have here. (3) Consider using MAE or truncated MAE (eg: `min(MAE, 3.5)`) as objective function. MSE severely penalizes large errors which causes small errors to be ignored. Truncated MAE works best (not perfect) for me.

Answer (score 1):

Using `lmfit` for this fitting problem would be straightforward, by creating a  `lmfit.Model` from your `gh_func`, with something like

```
from lmfit import Model
gh_model = Model(gh_func)
params = gh_model.make_params(x0=?, a=?, sig=?, h3=?, h4=?)
```

where those question marks would have to be initial values for the parameters in question.

Your use of `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` does not provide initial values for the variables.  Unfortunately, this does not raise an error or give an indication of a problem because the authors of `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` have lied to you by making initial values optional. Initial values for all parameters are always required for all non-linear least-squares analyses.  It is not a choice of the implementation, it is a feature of the mathematical algorithm. What `curve_fit` hides from you is that leaving `p0=None` makes all initial values 1.0. Whether that is remotely appropriate depends on the model and data being fit - it cannot be always reasonable.  As an example, if the `x` values for your data extended from 9000 to 9500, and the peak function was centered around 9200, starting with `x0` of 1 would almost certainly not find a suitable fit.  It is always deceptive to imply in any way that initial values are optional.  They just are not.  Not sometimes, not for well-defined problems.  Initial values are never, ever optional.

Initial values don't have to be perfect, but they need to be of the right scale.  Many people will warn you about "false minima" - getting stuck at a solution that is not bad but not "best". My experience is that the more common problem people run into is initial values that are so far off that the model is just not sensitive to small changes in their values, and so can never be optimized (with `x0=1,sig=1` for data with x on [9000, 9500] and centered at 9200 being exactly in that category).

The answer to your question for your essential question of "providing initial guesses for the parameters which are generated automatically" is hard to answer without knowing the properties of your model function. You might be able to use some heuristics to guess values from a data set. Lmfit has such heuristic "guess parameter values from data" functions for many peak-like functions.  You probably have some sense for the physical (or other domain) for `h3` and `h4` and know what kinds of values are reasonable, and can probably give better initial values than `h3=h4=1`. It might be that you want to start with guessing parameters as if the data was simple Gaussian (say, using `lmfit.Model.guess_from_peak()`) and then use the difference of that and your data to get the scale for `h3` and `h4`.