# How to efficiently use "LMFIT" in python curve fitting to a damped cosine wave

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, curve-fitting, least-squares, lmfit

I've the dataset(x & y) that I want to fit as a damped cosine like (1-A+A*cos(K*x))exp(-B*x) by using LMFIT ("non-linear least squares method") as the link (https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/intro.html). To do this, I've tried with the following piece of code, but can't fit properly. What is going wrong with my code? Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

```
x = [0, 1.3, 1.7, 1.72, 1.84, 1.98, 2.02, 2.16, 2.2, 2.2, 2.3, 2.38, 2.5, 2.55, 2.75, 2.8, 2.82, 2.84, 2.9, 2.92, 3.1, 3.13, 3.18, 3.19, 3.22, 3.3, 3.38, 3.44, 3.49, 3.62, 3.64, 3.72, 3.72, 3.75, 3.8, 3.82, 3.86, 3.92, 4.0, 4.07, 4.1, 4.1, 4.13, 4.14, 4.14, 4.17, 4.21, 4.24, 4.24, 4.24, 4.28, 4.3, 4.38, 4.49, 4.62, 4.62, 4.67, 4.72, 4.73, 4.74, 4.76, 4.76, 4.81, 4.81, 4.88, 4.89, 4.9, 4.9, 4.94, 4.96, 5.03, 5.05, 5.06, 5.1, 5.1, 5.15, 5.16, 5.16, 5.19, 5.22, 5.22, 5.3, 5.37, 5.41, 5.46, 5.56, 5.63, 5.65, 5.65, 5.73, 5.76, 5.81, 5.86, 5.91, 5.98, 6.03, 6.05, 6.05, 6.06, 6.11, 6.14, 6.22, 6.25, 6.27, 6.27, 6.3, 6.3, 6.31, 6.36, 6.42, 6.42, 6.47, 6.48, 6.5, 6.51, 6.58, 6.59, 6.62, 6.65, 6.66, 6.67, 6.69, 6.72, 6.77, 6.8, 6.84, 6.87, 6.91, 6.94, 6.94, 6.94, 7.05, 7.14, 7.17, 7.22, 7.23, 7.24, 7.32, 7.32, 7.35, 7.38, 7.4, 7.41, 7.42, 7.44, 7.45, 7.49, 7.5, 7.52, 7.54, 7.6, 7.72, 7.75, 7.81, 7.9, 7.92, 7.95, 7.97, 7.98, 7.99, 8.02, 8.03, 8.03, 8.05, 8.06, 8.07, 8.1, 8.12, 8.14, 8.19, 8.2, 8.21, 8.24, 8.25, 8.28, 8.28, 8.29, 8.32, 8.38, 8.38, 8.43, 8.49, 8.52, 8.54, 8.54, 8.57, 8.7, 8.75, 8.75, 8.78, 8.79, 8.88, 8.88, 8.93, 8.95, 9.0, 9.01, 9.02, 9.03, 9.06, 9.07, 9.11, 9.14, 9.16, 9.17, 9.18, 9.19, 9.2, 9.3, 9.33, 9.44, 9.46, 9.59, 9.62, 9.62, 9.64, 9.66, 9.71, 9.73, 9.73, 9.75, 9.76, 9.76, 9.79, 9.88, 9.9, 9.93, 9.93, 9.95, 9.99, 10.01, 10.03, 10.04, 10.05, 10.07, 10.11, 10.13, 10.18, 10.22, 10.22, 10.31, 10.37, 10.38, 10.41, 10.42, 10.44, 10.5, 10.52, 10.55, 10.56, 10.56, 10.58, 10.6, 10.66, 10.68, 10.68, 10.69, 10.7, 10.73, 10.75, 10.81, 10.93, 10.96, 10.98, 10.98, 11.02, 11.04, 11.1, 11.14, 11.15, 11.15, 11.17, 11.19, 11.21, 11.23, 11.24, 11.28, 11.3, 11.31, 11.32, 11.33, 11.4, 11.42, 11.48, 11.5, 11.51, 11.6, 11.62, 11.62, 11.63, 11.65, 11.72, 11.74, 11.74, 11.94, 11.95, 11.98, 12.02, 12.02, 12.03, 12.04, 12.09, 12.11, 12.17, 12.2, 12.23, 12.26, 12.3, 12.31, 12.33, 12.33, 12.37, 12.38, 12.61, 12.63, 12.69, 12.7, 12.74, 12.79, 12.8, 12.84, 12.87, 12.9, 12.91, 12.92, 12.94, 13.0, 13.19, 13.2, 13.26, 13.29, 13.3, 13.31, 13.31, 13.34, 13.35, 13.36, 13.44, 13.48, 13.52, 13.59, 13.78, 13.83, 13.88, 13.98, 14.02, 14.05, 14.07, 14.1, 14.14, 14.19, 14.25, 14.33, 14.36, 14.38, 14.41, 14.46, 14.47, 14.53, 14.54, 14.57, 14.69, 14.72, 14.77, 14.78, 14.78, 14.8, 14.82, 14.82, 14.91, 14.92, 14.96, 14.96, 15.05, 15.09, 15.17, 15.2, 15.21, 15.25, 15.26, 15.31, 15.32, 15.36, 15.36, 15.4, 15.4, 15.4, 15.41, 15.47, 15.52, 15.6, 15.61, 15.61, 15.63, 15.65, 15.71, 15.77, 15.8, 15.84, 15.86, 15.88, 15.94, 15.94, 15.97, 15.98, 16.02, 16.03, 16.27, 16.43, 16.56, 16.64, 16.64, 16.64, 16.68, 16.88, 16.91, 16.92, 16.93, 16.97, 16.99, 17.0, 17.01, 17.02, 17.05, 17.13, 17.21, 17.32, 17.45, 17.59, 17.79, 17.8, 17.81, 17.87, 17.9, 17.92, 17.93, 17.93, 17.97, 17.98, 18.02, 18.05, 18.08, 18.11, 18.2, 18.24, 18.4, 18.48, 18.5, 18.51, 18.59, 18.65, 18.76, 18.76, 18.86, 18.86, 18.86, 18.87, 18.9, 18.92, 18.93, 19.05, 19.06, 19.17, 19.26, 19.27, 19.41, 19.47, 19.48, 19.54, 19.6, 19.66, 19.67, 19.68, 19.8, 19.9, 20.01, 20.04, 20.1, 20.49, 20.49, 20.5, 20.56, 20.65, 20.65, 20.7, 20.71, 20.78, 20.91, 21.11, 21.19, 21.2, 21.28, 21.29, 21.58, 21.62, 21.7, 21.7, 21.76, 21.76, 21.84, 21.85, 21.87, 21.9, 21.94, 22.0, 22.02, 22.09, 22.16, 22.3, 22.3, 22.41, 22.51, 22.53, 22.71, 22.77, 22.94, 23.17, 23.25, 23.33, 23.72, 23.87, 24.12, 24.14, 24.19, 24.34, 24.4, 24.6, 24.62, 24.62, 24.8, 25.01, 25.13, 25.4, 25.42, 25.81, 25.85, 25.89, 26.03, 26.17, 26.22, 26.41, 26.98, 27.01, 27.02, 27.06, 27.17, 27.49, 27.73, 28.14, 28.23, 28.37, 28.56, 28.83, 28.84, 30.32, 30.57, 31.95, 33.23, 33.46, 33.81, 33.85, 34.44]
y = [1, 0.96826171875, 0.9541015625, 0.99658203125, 0.98828125, 0.98046875, 0.9931640625, 0.99365234375, 0.96435546875, 0.98388671875, 0.984375, 0.98486328125, 0.97412109375, 0.986328125, 0.900390625, 0.662109375, 0.994140625, 0.59716796875, 0.9833984375, 0.97802734375, 0.94873046875, 0.99169921875, 0.9755859375, 0.88330078125, 0.98583984375, 0.96630859375, 0.974609375, 0.9677734375, 0.9345703125, 0.7783203125, 0.95556640625, 0.90576171875, 0.9765625, 0.9794921875, 0.896484375, 0.984375, 0.97314453125, 0.96240234375, 0.96044921875, 0.95361328125, 0.6123046875, 0.919921875, 0.9833984375, 0.90869140625, 0.98095703125, 0.890625, 0.96923828125, 0.425048828125, 0.611328125, 0.96484375, 0.9560546875, 0.464111328125, 0.97705078125, 0.50634765625, 0.841796875, 0.93896484375, 0.96240234375, 0.9501953125, 0.8857421875, 0.806640625, 0.884765625, 0.96533203125, 0.677734375, 0.9169921875, 0.88427734375, 0.90966796875, 0.91259765625, 0.97021484375, 0.9736328125, 0.9619140625, 0.841796875, 0.9736328125, 0.87353515625, 0.79931640625, 0.92626953125, 0.966796875, 0.95263671875, 0.966796875, 0.96240234375, 0.552734375, 0.9443359375, 0.9248046875, 0.91748046875, 0.97021484375, 0.85400390625, 0.70751953125, 0.9658203125, 0.90185546875, 0.916015625, 0.91650390625, 0.95654296875, 0.953125, 0.77294921875, 0.814453125, 0.40673828125, 0.8583984375, 0.8779296875, 0.89892578125, 0.31005859375, 0.495849609375, 0.9189453125, 0.94921875, 0.89990234375, 0.6923828125, 0.7294921875, 0.85302734375, 0.95947265625, 0.890625, 0.9384765625, 0.8779296875, 0.93359375, 0.391357421875, 0.779296875, 0.93505859375, 0.9423828125, 0.93359375, 0.841796875, 0.9345703125, 0.58154296875, 0.92919921875, 0.947265625, 0.94580078125, 0.84375, 0.93359375, 0.921875, 0.9189453125, 0.8955078125, 0.61474609375, 0.8369140625, 0.87060546875, 0.8740234375, 0.356201171875, 0.892578125, 0.73876953125, 0.93310546875, 0.88330078125, 0.826171875, 0.80810546875, 0.984375, 0.919921875, 0.1849365234375, 0.89404296875, 0.83984375, 0.91455078125, 0.2366943359375, 0.73193359375, 0.65380859375, 0.779296875, 0.94140625, 0.8564453125, 0.79150390625, 0.67041015625, 0.266357421875, 0.290771484375, 0.677734375, 0.89501953125, 0.4091796875, 0.87255859375, 0.87255859375, 0.389892578125, 0.90478515625, 0.403076171875, 0.68896484375, 0.83642578125, 0.8486328125, 0.5771484375, 0.8642578125, 0.93359375, 0.7734375, 0.72900390625, 0.853515625, 0.87890625, 0.7587890625, 0.2391357421875, 0.8671875, 0.9501953125, 0.92041015625, 0.869140625, 0.90576171875, 0.95947265625, 0.77734375, 0.2017822265625, 0.82568359375, 0.6015625, 0.8935546875, 0.12481689453125, 0.89697265625, 0.6240234375, 0.86865234375, 0.9130859375, 0.470947265625, 0.75439453125, 0.8486328125, 0.67529296875, 0.87451171875, 0.9755859375, 0.71826171875, 0.91796875, 0.70751953125, 0.80908203125, 0.89208984375, 0.79541015625, 0.7236328125, 0.81103515625, 0.84814453125, 0.59765625, 0.7529296875, 0.234375, 0.68896484375, 0.849609375, 0.69970703125, 0.82861328125, 0.87939453125, 0.322509765625, 0.84326171875, 0.4404296875, 0.78369140625, 0.58154296875, 0.796875, 0.84814453125, 0.28759765625, 0.5263671875, 0.71044921875, 0.8388671875, 0.94580078125, 0.3125, 0.1378173828125, 0.81591796875, 0.85009765625, 0.84521484375, 0.779296875, 0.45751953125, 0.84033203125, 0.58447265625, 0.921875, 0.51123046875, 0.82421875, 0.80224609375, 0.2000732421875, 0.90771484375, 0.4267578125, 0.58154296875, 0.78173828125, 0.736328125, 0.8173828125, 0.65087890625, 0.66357421875, 0.900390625, 0.923828125, 0.66162109375, 0.76513671875, 0.73974609375, 0.6943359375, 0.96044921875, 0.4091796875, 0.529296875, 0.82861328125, 0.7333984375, 0.81689453125, 0.73583984375, 0.66259765625, 0.72607421875, 0.8125, 0.47802734375, 0.646484375, 0.1658935546875, 0.80615234375, 0.59716796875, 0.724609375, 0.2113037109375, 0.301025390625, 0.45947265625, 0.22216796875, 0.62744140625, 0.61865234375, 0.8662109375, 0.7998046875, 0.7333984375, 0.771484375, 0.57373046875, -0.135009765625, 0.6455078125, 0.39404296875, 0.76513671875, 0.603515625, 0.76025390625, 0.630859375, 0.114013671875, 0.63671875, 0.75537109375, 0.1390380859375, 0.27001953125, 0.73681640625, 0.78271484375, 0.7646484375, -0.005977630615234375, 0.402099609375, 0.7119140625, 0.75244140625, 0.71484375, 0.64990234375, 0.3974609375, 0.333251953125, -0.004974365234375, 0.94873046875, 0.348876953125, 0.27880859375, 0.77783203125, 0.67529296875, 0.421875, 0.66357421875, 0.73388671875, 0.6640625, 0.70263671875, 0.48486328125, 0.25537109375, 0.6337890625, 0.4765625, 0.560546875, 0.75439453125, 0.1290283203125, 0.75390625, 0.67138671875, -0.06591796875, 0.7421875, 0.671875, 0.62109375, 0.487548828125, 0.61181640625, 0.56787109375, -0.158447265625, 0.767578125, 0.2235107421875, 0.701171875, 0.05010986328125, 0.60986328125, 0.7255859375, 0.646484375, 0.368896484375, 0.623046875, 0.7177734375, -0.1337890625, 0.69677734375, 0.68408203125, 0.64794921875, 0.433349609375, 0.5302734375, 0.8076171875, 0.39306640625, 0.70361328125, 0.55810546875, 0.7392578125, 0.59765625, 0.91748046875, 0.2086181640625, -0.00395965576171875, 0.11541748046875, 0.4501953125, 0.9111328125, 0.5673828125, 0.278076171875, 0.55029296875, 0.53271484375, 0.6103515625, 0.2529296875, 0.374755859375, 0.6416015625, -0.0623779296875, 0.6845703125, 0.75537109375, 0.853515625, -0.1517333984375, 0.77294921875, 0.55517578125, 0.51318359375, 0.62353515625, 0.5771484375, 0.53515625, 0.324951171875, 0.1741943359375, 0.619140625, -0.174560546875, 0.1729736328125, 0.33642578125, 0.58544921875, 0.59033203125, 0.66845703125, 0.50244140625, 0.01486968994140625, 0.3740234375, 0.442138671875, 0.249755859375, 0.52685546875, 0.17822265625, 0.036163330078125, 0.0174560546875, -0.272705078125, 0.072998046875, 0.14208984375, 0.81298828125, 0.28955078125, 0.371337890625, 0.499755859375, 0.311767578125, 0.63330078125, 0.7138671875, 0.358154296875, -0.04681396484375, -0.1251220703125, 0.32763671875, 0.049652099609375, 0.449951171875, 0.469970703125, 0.1090087890625, 0.34326171875, 0.040740966796875, 0.43017578125, 0.311767578125, 0.043548583984375, -0.2294921875, 0.2281494140625, -0.26611328125, 0.5087890625, 0.76904296875, 0.058685302734375, 0.6572265625, 0.51318359375, 0.7578125, -0.036712646484375, 0.311767578125, 0.025726318359375, 0.041351318359375, 0.0687255859375, 0.342529296875, 0.375732421875, 0.316162109375, 0.466796875, 0.371337890625, 0.07318115234375, 0.6201171875, 0.63623046875, 0.425048828125, 0.38134765625, -0.263916015625, -0.26513671875, 0.364990234375, 0.454833984375, -0.27001953125, 0.43017578125, 0.2164306640625, 0.335693359375, 0.310302734375, 0.447998046875, -0.1202392578125, 0.33740234375, 0.383544921875, -0.447509765625, -0.076904296875, 0.0176544189453125, 0.52587890625, 0.6865234375, 0.59375, -0.2413330078125, 0.38671875, 0.355224609375, 0.403564453125, 0.58154296875, 0.426025390625, 0.0280609130859375, -0.342041015625, -0.06524658203125, 0.2734375, 0.01151275634765625, -0.00833892822265625, 0.2269287109375, -0.1380615234375, 0.55712890625, -0.01837158203125, 0.36474609375, 0.52099609375, -0.353759765625, 0.356689453125, -0.11865234375, 0.2734375, 0.07598876953125, -0.207763671875, 0.1864013671875, 0.11090087890625, 0.08856201171875, -0.441162109375, 0.197998046875, -0.11285400390625, 0.1878662109375, 0.50537109375, -0.40576171875, -0.2386474609375, 0.0860595703125, -0.38720703125, -0.192626953125, -0.313232421875, 0.478759765625, -0.4306640625, -0.0682373046875, 0.01105499267578125, -0.14013671875, 0.23583984375, 0.26025390625, -0.255859375, -0.37548828125, 0.0772705078125, -0.21728515625, 0.279296875, 0.153564453125, -0.389892578125, 0.45361328125, -0.11083984375, 0.466064453125, 0.44287109375, -0.3984375, -0.16552734375, 0.3984375, -0.1669921875, -0.11944580078125, -0.1561279296875, 0.441650390625, -0.194091796875, -0.429443359375, 0.00981903076171875, 0.2122802734375, -0.151123046875, 0.019500732421875, -0.192138671875, -0.1365966796875, 0.1016845703125, -0.10931396484375, 0.139404296875, -0.454833984375, -0.353515625, 0.26953125, -0.41650390625, -0.41162109375, 0.303955078125, 0.0335693359375, -0.1527099609375, -0.396728515625, 0.1541748046875, 0.302001953125, 0.461181640625, -0.26953125, -0.244873046875, -0.128173828125, -0.1346435546875, -0.2939453125, 0.1932373046875, 0.0312042236328125, 0.04608154296875, -0.351806640625, -0.11907958984375, -0.005191802978515625, -0.29296875, -0.1134033203125, -0.09002685546875]

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import least_squares
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters, Parameter, report_fit
x = np.asarray(x); y = np.asarray(y)

def fit_fc(params, t, data):
    A = params['A'].value
    K = params['K'].value
    B = params['B'].value
    model = (1-A+A*np.cos(K * t))*np.exp(-1 * B * t)
    return model - data 

params = Parameters()
params.add('A', value=.9, min =0, max =1)
params.add('K', value=0.42, min=-0.2, max=0.8)
params.add('B', value=0.1, min=.01, max=.1)
result = minimize(fit_fc, params, args=(x, y), method='leastsq')
report_fit(params) # write error report
y_lsq = (1-result.params['A'] + (result.params['A']  *np.cos(result.params['K']*x))*np.exp(result.params['B'])*x*(-1))
#plot results
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', label='Data')
plt.plot(x, y_lsq, label='Least_Square_Method')
plt.xlabel('$x$')
plt.ylabel('$y$')
plt.legend()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can't fit properly"? What's the "proper" result and what result are you currently getting?

Comment: @ForceBru, can you please suggest for the improvement of the plot? I've edit the code as well as the topic of the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your script to use `lmfit.Model`, which is sort of easier for curve fitting.  That would look like (removing the data for simplicity):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lmfit import Model, Parameters
x = np.asarray(x)
y = np.asarray(y)

def damped_cosine(t, a, k, b):
    return (1-a+a*np.cos(k*t))*np.exp(-b*t)

params = Parameters()
params.add('a', value=0.9, min=0)
params.add('k', value=0.42)
params.add('b', value=0.1)

dmodel = Model(damped_cosine)
result = dmodel.fit(y, params, t=x)
print(result.fit_report())

result.plot_fit(show_init=True)

plt.show()
```

I've removed most of the Parameters bounds -- don't use arbitrary and tight bounds unless you know you need to do so, and if you have not even plotted your data, then you definitely do not know that.

The report printed for this fit is

```
[[Model]]
    Model(damped_cosine)
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 42
    # data points      = 562
    # variables        = 3
    chi-square         = 42.2473566
    reduced chi-square = 0.07557667
    Akaike info crit   = -1448.43356
    Bayesian info crit = -1435.43905
[[Variables]]
    a:  1.1104e-10 +/- 0.00205742 (1852835584.87%) (init = 0.9)
    k:  0.45910709 +/- 170843.547 (37212134.66%) (init = 0.42)
    b:  0.05936966 +/- 0.00309385 (5.21%) (init = 0.1)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are < 0.100)
    C(a, b) = -0.707
```

and the plot of the data and fit (and initial guess) is

[image]

I think that the most obvious conclusion is that a damped oscillatory function is not a very convincing representation of your data.  There is not anything like a clear complete oscillation.

Comment: @M Newville, many thanks for your response. I've checked the script (& result as well). If I choose the initial guess ('A =0.74; K = 0.2; B = 0.025') then the fitted plot outperforms (visual point of view) in the region ('x=0' to 'x = 15') and this is expected for my case. But, I'm worried, how to defend this nature of the fitted plot? Any idea or suggestions is highly appreciated. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to plot the figure ? Your data is really "noisy" compared to the fit you are attempting.

Comment: yes I've tried with another approach in the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69505628/plotting-the-best-fit-of-a-damped-cosine-function/69514629?noredirect=1#comment122913712_69514629. With 'LMFIT', I try to fit the plot better. Thanks